# How Can I Hide Specific Elements on a Razor View Based on Security without Logic in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked all over for elegant solutions to this not so age-old question.  How can I lock down form elements within an ASP.Net MVC View, without adding if...then logic all over the place?
Ideally the BaseController, either from OnAuthorization, or OnResultExecultion, would check the rendering form elements and hide/not render them based on role and scope.
Another approach I have considered is writing some sort of custom attributes, so as to stay consistent with how how we lock down ActionResults with [Authorize].  Is this even possible without passing a list of hidden objects to the view and putting if's all over?

Other background info: We will have a database that will tell us at execution time (based on user role/scope) what elements will be hidden.  We are using MVC3 with Razor Viewengine.  We're utilizing a BaseController where any of the Controller methods can be overridden.

Any help on this would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a number of different methods:

1. Send the user to a different view (display only view) based on the action filter, or a condition in the controller.
2. On a field basis, you could build the logic into the editor templates to read custom data-annotations based on role/permission.
3. You can build HTML helpers to handle the logic and render the appropriate partial view, css class, or text.

For more reading:

- [How much logic is allowed in ASP.NET
  MVC views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443193/how-much-logic-is-allowed-in-asp-net-mvc-views)
- [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) (there are 5 parts, very informative and a good place to start developing your own editor templates)

Comment: #1 is not an option, but we have considered #2 and #3.  #2 works but I  prefer not to use JS to decide what to hide.  I am leaning toward #3, although I would have preferred not to override every existing helper to add security in.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Zacho - #2 does not use JS (javascript) for anything. The conditional logic is encapsulated to a single template where the output is controlled by the Model.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I am a little confused what the difference is between #2 and #3.

Comment: #2 is related directly to how a model property is rendered through the editor template. Is this what you are attempting to do? Specifically the output of something like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)` for example.